# how to configure IIS6 and up to use .net 3.5 with a VDir of .net 1.1?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis

I have a site built on .net 3.5 I need to have a virtual directory in it for another site built on .net 1.1. I have created to application pools in IIS and each are set to the right version number but it still doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remark: 
just a remark that iis has the no .net 3.5 among its options. In fact .net 3.5 runtime is the same as .net 2.0 runtime, its just the Base class library which is different but the runtime versions are the same

Comment: Thanks I understand but the issue is inheritance I think. When the 1.1 web.config tries to read the root web.config it obviously fails. I tried removing the the lines that fail. No help there. I tried removing the root web.config and placing a web.config in each folder of the root site but still no help. How do you run a 1.1 VDir under a more recent frame work?

Comment: there is a tag that we put in the parent web.config that tells that a particular section is not inheritable to child web.configs. this allows nesting of .net applications with different versions. but i really cant't remember the tag name

Comment: Thanks for the response. The tag is <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">. how ever there are certain tags that you can't include in this tag. And it's some to those tags that are causing my issues.